# SDL Web Developer Summit India 2016

Tags: discussion

The SDL India Community will be hosting 2nd SDL Web Developer Summit  in New Delhi, India From 5th to 6th Feb 2016.

This is an excellent opportunity to learn, meet and share with SDL professionals and product teams from India and abroad. The focus would be around SDL Web and integrations with other SDL products.

For registration, agenda and more info, please follow the link: https://community.sdl.com/developers/sdl-developer-summit-india-2016/c/e/179

Thanks

Comment: Awesome!!! Make this a success guys by joining in maximum numbers

Comment: Just to add on:
There are special offers for MVPs joining the event.
There are quite a good prizes to won by the participants
and there are nice goodies will be distributed to each participants

Comment: Great, looking forward to it !!

Comment: Almost there... flight booked, hotel half booked.